# What is the maximum limit of long varchar in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

What is the maximum limit of long varchar in Mysql? 
I am using hibernate 3.2
When I tried to save a large value, and failed to save.

Comment: hello amal thr is already ans about this question so here is the [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592702/mysql-varchar-size-limit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`LONG VARCHAR` datatype is just a synonym for `MEDIUMTEXT` (thus is for compatibility reasons for ODBC). The length is `16,777,215` bytes for this data type.

You can also refer to the manual: [The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-type-overview.html)