# What is the C# equivalent datatype of LONG VARCHAR in Oracle SQL?

Tags: c#, oracle

Could not find a equivalent datatype of Long Varchar in C#

Varchar has max limit of 4000 bytes, so an alternative of concatenating string query to obtain the objective can be done but having a long Varchar equivalent would solve the problem better.

Comment: how about string?

Comment: string accepts only varchar and varchar2 and doesnt not accept Long Varchar which has max capacity of 32K bytes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL VARCHAR size limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592702/mysql-varchar-size-limit)

Comment: It is not duplicate I have asked for the data type equivalent and did not ask about the max data size equivalent

Comment: There is no `long varchar` in Oracle SQL.  There is `long` which has been depricated for more than a decade.  There is also a `clob` which allows you to store multiple TB of text.  Are you referring to one of those two data types?

Comment: I am using Oracle SQL 18.4.0.376 and it has Long Varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any datatype which can hold characters to the size as that of `Long Varchar`. However, better than string concatenation, you might go with `xml` datatype of SQL server (`SqlDbType.Xml` in c#) instead once you have transformed the string to a well-formed XML document.

You can create XML for your very long string like this:

```
var myLongString = "some very long string";
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
doc.AppendChild(docNode);

XmlNode productsNode = doc.CreateElement("root");
doc.AppendChild(productsNode);

XmlNode productNode = doc.CreateElement("text");
productNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(myLongString));
productsNode.AppendChild(productNode);
doc.Save();
```